# Accelerate application startup on Jetty

Tags: java, performance, jpa, jetty, guice

I have a small web application configured with [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) and [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/), and run this application on jetty (8.0.0.M1) during development. There are about 10 (small) JPA managed classes (entities and embeddables), and about 20 classes total.

The initial startup takes 15 seconds + 5 seconds for the first requests. It seems like JPA is working on the first request, since I have the table generation strategy "create" enabled and see some JPA output from Maven on the first request.

A reload takes about 10 seconds and the first request after reloading takes about 3 to 4 seconds.

You may think, that the startup time is not so bad, but I'm wondering if I could accelerate the startup to work more fluently like with Django. Any idea for startup tuning?

Comment: Is your concern the startup time per se, or that the first user has to pay the startup cost?  If it's the latter, you could have your application send request(s) to itself on startup just to warm it up.  Then the first user sees a normal response time.

Comment: My concern is the startup time during development. Restarts are relatively rare in production so I would accept that the first user must wait a few seconds.

Comment: If you restart due to code changes (not schema changes), try avoiding restarts (almost) completely with JRebel (http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/). It's not free, but it saves a lot of time (I am by no means affiliated with them).

Comment: It's probably JPA rather than Jetty. I use Jetty and code changes are reflected instantly, although I also use JPA which slows down the first startup.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that if you are not prepared to remove the table creation strategy, you will have to tolerate such loading times. In essence, everytime your startup your application, it will drop/create/verify the tables and issue the correct DDL statements to make it match the entities in your package.

Assuming that you're done defining your entities and you are working on some business-logic code, you can create the database once, and just re-use your initial setup.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are using Jetty for rapid application development (RAD) and you want to see and test out any changes as quickly as possible. If there is no actual "persistent" requirement on your RAD environment's database, you could try moving to an im-memory DB engine. DB engine's like HSQL allow you to spin up new tables (and other structures) very rapidly compared to actual production quality DB engines. This would require that you use an ORM because HSQL's SQL is very different then most other databases but it sounds like you are already using JPA so this shouldn't be difficult.

The only alternative I see is using a database which has it's schema already created appropriately and not dropping it every time.